# how to tell clipsmm where to find clips?

Tags: c++, c, linux, clips

I'm trying to compile clipsmm on linux ubuntu 14.04.
Clips is already compiled with a libclips.a generated.
Glibmm and sigc++ are also compiled and "make install" to default category.Only one thing left, after reading over and over clipsmm's main page and mailinglist still cannot get a clue, HOW TO TELL CLIPSMM WHERE TO FIND CLIPS??
Do I have to rewrite configure file? Or just put clips into clipsmm's root derectory, but with what structure?

Please, if there's anyone have experience the compilation of clipsmm, any help will be appreciate!

Comment: It would be useful to know how you got as far as you did. I downloaded clipsmm-0.3.4.tar.bz2 and couldn't get past the first step listed in the INSTALL file: entering './configure' and 'sh ./configure'. I tried in both the top level directory and the clipsmm directory and the shell responded with either  'No such file or directory' or 'Can't open ./configure'. I assume there are additional build tools required by clipsmm that aren't preinstalled in ubuntu.

Comment: yes, you have to use "autoreconf -fi"to generate a configure file from configure.ac.you may find autoreconf through "apt-get" command. That INSTALL doesn't help much, it seems every project generate by automake ,will have a INSTALL like that.